# Django rest-framework Social Oauth2: How to set permission classes per view or method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to set permission per view or method using [Django rest-framework Social Oauth2](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2).

How should I set permission to each view or method?

At first, I've tried to set 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' in settings.py. But some method doesn't need authentication, I'd like to set AllowAny. So, I've tried to set decorator to the method but it doesn't work.

settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {   
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

views.py

```py
@permission_classes([AllowAny, ])
@api_view(['POST'])
def someMethod(request):
    return foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by myself. Commented out DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES on settings.py. And imported these Authentification and authentication_classes on views.py.

settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        # 'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication
from rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication import SocialAuthentication

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication, SocialAuthentication]

    def someMethodNeedAuth:
         return foo


@authentication_classes([AllowAny, ])
@api_view(['POST'])
def someMethodAllowAny(request):
    return bar
```